# Setting Property with dot notation vs bracket notation

Tags: delegates

This sets the delegate correctly and everything functions as normal:

```
    UINavigationController *nc = [segue destinationViewController];
    RecipeAddViewController *rc = [nc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    rc.delegate = self;
```

When I do:

```
    [[[[[segue destinationViewController] viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0]delegate]self];
```

The delegate method is never called. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

The '.' Syntax would call getter and setter based on the usage. However in message syntax we need to call the explicit setter like bellow.

```
    [[[[segue destinationViewController] viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0] setDelegate:self]
```